# Nested data get request Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how to get data when I am using a foreign key. I mean, I have a *many-to-one* relation, but when I get data I don’t receive the response how I would like it.

```
class AsigManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, Nom_Asig, horario):
        return self.get(Nom_Asig=Nom_Asig, horario=horario)

class ProfManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, Nombre, profesion):
        return self.get(Nombre=Nombre, profesion=profesion)

class Asignatura(models.Model):
    Nom_Asig = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    horario = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    objects = AsigManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['Nom_Asig', 'horario']]

class Profesor(models.Model):
    asignatura = models.ForeignKey(Asignatura, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    profesion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = AsigManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['Nombre', 'profesion']]


class ProfesorView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        profe = list(Profesor.objects.values())
        if len(profe)>0:
            datos = {'message':'Succes','Profesores: ':profe}
        else:
            datos = {'message':'Profesor Not Found...'}
        return JsonResponse(datos)
```

But I *would* like to get the Asignatura data when I get the Professor data, such as an object or a list inside the Professor request.

[image]

Comment: What kind of get request? An HTML [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request? Or something else?

Comment: Just get request